# Can't able to connect to Database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection

I have installed the MySQL server using XAMMP.Created a new database with some data using phpmyadmin.Then i tried to connect to database using this code.But it did not connect.It shows me an error.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing!");
            SqlConnection myco = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;User Id=root;database=customer;Trusted_Connection=yes");
            try
            {
                myco.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:
http://pastebin.com/MyEtk4w6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have MySql then you need to use the classes for MySql not the ones used for SqlServer

```
 MySqlConnection myco = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=customer;" + 
                                            "Uid=username;Pwd=password;");
```

Also the connection string for MySql is different

```
  Server=localhost;Database=customer;Uid=username;Pwd=password;
```

The connection strings for MySql could be very numerous, you should check the correct one for your requirement here at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using a ***SqlConnection*** object which is for ***Microsoft SQL Server***.

Use a ***MySQLConnection*** instead.